# Trouble rendering a variable in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to "create" a variable and render it in my template but for some reason I can't manage to do it.

Here's my view.py:

```
def test(request):
  person = {'firstname': 'Craig', 'lastname': 'Daniels'}
  weather = "sunny"
  context = {
    'person': person,
    'weather': weather,
  }
  return render(request, 'home/dashboard.html', context)
```

In my template: dashboard.html :

```
<h1>Hi {{ person.firstname }} {{ person.lastname }}</h1>
```

Any idea on what could be wrong?

Comment: is your view function properly indented?

Comment: What do you see in your rendered template?

Comment: @harryghgim yes it is , I am actually using Pycharm so indentation is not a issue.

Comment: @Lomtrur I only see the text "Hi" , so it seems that just the variable is not being rendered.

Comment: Try changing the "Hi" to something else, to confirm that your path to the template is correct and please include the content of your `urls.py` file to confirm that you are calling the right view.

Comment: @Lomtrur I changed the initial text and django behaved accordingly though I still can't get my variable rendered. As for the urls.py , I'm calling this view from a 'home' app and as for the main urls.py file I added the following code:  `path('', include('home.urls'))`. Inside the home app folder though, I have not set up any urls in there but I guess this shouldn't be an issue right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try writing URLs in urls.py like below:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from projectapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^home/$',  views.home),
]
```